# submit form when input text is change jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, onchange

I am using a price range, ie jquery range slider.
And i have two text fields and price range slider below image

Image

[image]

HTML Code

```
<form name="range_form" method="post">
INR <input type="text" id="amount1" name="amount1" >
- INR <input type="text" id="amount2" name="amount2" >
</form>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

jQuery Code

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 99999,
        values: [ 75, 300 ], 
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount1" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ]);            
            $( "#amount2" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ]);            
        }
    });

    $("#amount1").val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ));
    $("#amount2").val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ));

});
```

And above code is to displays the price range is two text fields.

Now My Question starts here...

How can i submit `form` when `input text` field is change.

I have tried working with `keyup` , `keydown` , `onchange` but working what i am looking for.

Cos I am not inserting the values in `text` field from keyboard, it gets the values from `slider ranges`.. so how i can submit when text field is changed.

Comment: first things first whats the ID of your form? i see you have given a Name to your form but not an ID and are you using any input element with the type="submit" anywhere in form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `stop` event handler to your slider widget to submit the form when the user stops sliding:

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 99999,
    values: [ 75, 300 ], 
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount1" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ]);            
        $( "#amount2" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ]);            
    },
    stop : function (event, ui) {
        $('#range_form').trigger('submit');
    }
});
```

This will trigger a `submit` event on the parent form of the slider widget. Note that I selected the form by ID so you will have to add an ID to the form, or change the selection for the form to: `$('[name="range_form"]')` (this is much less effecient).

Docs for the `stop` event: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-stop

Comment: @Rafee `Its not working` isn't very descriptive. Can you post a link to the "not working" code or paste in some error text?

Comment: `stop : function (event, ui) {
        $('#range_form').trigger('submit');
    }` And i  gave my form id as `range_form` but its not triggering

Comment: @Rafee Here is a JSFiddle showing that my code does work isolated: http://jsfiddle.net/PaBzT/. Notice that I added an ID to the form tag, that was the issue, you weren't selecting anything because there was no element with the ID you were selecting (the form had a name but no ID).

Comment: try `$("#range_form").submit();` instead of `$('#range_form').trigger('submit');` also i agree with @Jasper you should give an ID to that form...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `change` event of the slider http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#events

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 99999,
    values: [ 75, 300 ], 
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount1" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ]);            
        $( "#amount2" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ]);            
    },
    change: function(event, ui){
        // do what you want.. a change has occured to the slider..
    }
})
```

It will get fired whenever you stop using the slider, or whenever a change to the slider happens programmatically..